# AWK processing "()" on the input stream

Tags: bash, awk

in the following:

```
echo "private public () " | awk 'BEGIN{kw="private"}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if (kw~$i) print $i}'
```

i get the error:

```
awk: run time error: regular expression compile failed (missing operand)
()
```

this is caused by the parenthesis in the input stream. How can i let the awk know that it should not interpret the parenthesis in the input stream?

Thanks

Comment: I think you probably meant: `$i ~ kw`, since you want to know if the field includes `kw`. Although possibly you just want to test for equality, as Ed Morton suggests. `kw ~ $i` makes little sense.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're asking "how do I get awk not to treat my string as a regexp" and the answer to that is always - don't write code that uses your string as a regexp. Just change `~` to `==` so you're doing a string comparison instead of a regexp comparison.

If that's not all you need then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input/output.

Comment: please have a look at my response

Comment: Your response is wrong in several ways (you don't need sed and a pipe when you're using awk, and you shouldn't be using a regexp comparison at all). Did you try what I suggested? If so, in what way did it not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I think that i got it the right way :
if (kw~$i)
I want to check it the term ($i) is a member of the keywork (kw) list
Thank you for the response:

The solution that i came up with was the prefix with:
sed 's/[()]/\&/g'
This escapes the brackets so that the regex interpreter leaves them alone, so i have:

echo "private public () " | sed 's/[()]/\&/g' | awk 'BEGIN{kw="private"}{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)if (kw~$i) print $i}'

This works, but i was looking for something a bit more elegant.

Comment: you don't need sed and a pipe when you're using awk, and you shouldn't be using a regexp comparison at all. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50783856/1745001). Also if you have a list of keywords as stated in this answer instead of a single keyword as shown in your question then your approach is completely wrong - you should be using an array with keyword indices and the `in` operator for comparison.

Comment: I like the idea of using an array better. That way:
1. I don't need to use a regex 
2. i don't need the sed because the () wont be a problem any more

Thanks